# How is regression testing done in scala using sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, regression-testing

I have many projects in a scala application that have classes in main/ and the unit tests in test/. Say the project is on version 0.2. I'd like to be able to run the tests in test/ with a version 0.1's classes that were in main/.

Is there a way to do it in sbt?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not called regression testing. You have a revised suite of tests, and you want to run those tests against version 0.1 of your application.

You will need to create an environment specifically for 0.1. Then, upgrade your tests in that environment to 0.2. Perform your testing on 0.1 as usual.

However, the multiple environment thing is not directly handled by sbt. sbt would only be used to run the tests in each environment.